# How to drain the well with the Song of Storms

Tags: zelda-ocarina-of-time

My 6 year old son is playing Zelda and needs to drain the well in Kakariko Village but needs to know how to become an adult first? Also, he's been trying to figure out how to play the Song of Storms on Gamecube. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

You need to enter the [windmill](http://zeldawiki.org/Kakariko_Windmill) in the back of Kakariko Village and pull out the Ocarina of Time in front of Guru-Guru as adult Link to learn the [Song of Storms](http://zeldawiki.org/Song_of_Storms).

From [Zelda Wiki](http://zeldawiki.org/Guru-Guru#Ocarina_of_Time):

> In Ocarina of Time, the Windmill Man stands inside the Kakariko Windmill playing his Phonograph. If adult Link pulls out his Ocarina of Time in front of him, he will teach Link the "Song of Storms." If young Link plays the song inside the windmill, it will start spinning really fast, draining Kakariko's well and opening the way to the Bottom of the Well.

In order to become adult Link, simply continue following the story. Shortly after the [third dungeon](http://zeldawiki.org/Inside_Jabu-Jabu%27s_Belly), you'll receive the [Master Sword](http://zeldawiki.org/Master_Sword) from the [Temple of Time](http://zeldawiki.org/Temple_of_Time) and become an adult.

You don't actually need to drain the well until much later in the game, though. The natural order of gameplay involves entering the [Bottom of the Well](http://zeldawiki.org/Bottom_of_the_Well) shortly before the [seventh dungeon](http://zeldawiki.org/Shadow_Temple).

---

As for the Gamecube Ocarina controls, the A button is still the same and the C-stick can be used in place of the C-buttons. You can also use Y as left-C, X as right-C, and Z as down-C. You can find more information on controls [on StrategyWiki](http://strategywiki.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Zelda:_Ocarina_of_Time/Controls).

Comment: This part always confused me because for the rest of the game it felt like you do something as young Link -> then you go to the future and observe the change. But for the Song of Storms you go to the future first, learn the song, and then come back and play it as young Link.

Comment: @originaluser It's actually an interesting time paradox. Link learns the Song of Storms as an adult from the man who learned it from child Link playing it.

Comment: @Brian careful, many fandoms will attack you for calling that a paradox (despite the [life-eater calling it one](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/StableTimeLoop)). :P  It actually forms what they call a "stable time loop" - without the interference of another time traveler, you prevent it from being a paradox by closing the loop when you play the song as a child.  An outside observer might be going "yeah, but where did the song come from in the first place?"  And the answer is "Steven Moffat wrote it."

Answer (score 3):

**Let the game progress naturally.** I can't tell if your question is a result of too much or too little walkthroughs, but either way you should relax and just play the game following the plot. If he doesn't know how to become an adult he doesn't need the song.

Song of storms is integral part of the story, you can't miss it.

Becoming an adult is integral part of the story. You can't miss it.

If you don't know how to progress the story listen to what [Navi, your fairy](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Navi) is saying. All will come in due time.

Comment: All I hear is "Hey, listen!"

Comment: Yes! My son does rush thru ..... But little by little hes getting it.He gets excited but hes learning theres more to it then just getting by. Thanku to those who haved helped. We appreciate it!